# Printing wrong average in C

Tags: c

Noob here. I'm learning C. and I faced this problem I couldn't find the error/bug in my code, everytime it prints the average of the program the value of 2686776 whatever the input is. I'm using Dev-C++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int loop, money, total, avg;
    total = 0;
    loop = 0;

    while(loop < 4) {
        printf("Money Spent");
        scanf("%d", &money);
        total = total + money;
        loop = loop + 1;
    }

    avg = total / 4;
    printf(" average %d", &avg);

    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove the `&` from the printf statement otherwise you print the address of this variable.

Also `avg` is `int` so it can't have decimal digits! (e.g. 4, 5 -> 9 -> avg = 4). So you have to change it to `float` or `double`

Answer (score 4):

Remove `&` from the `printf` argument and better declare `avg`  as `float` and change

```
avg = total / 4;
printf(" average %d", &avg);
```

to

```
avg = total / 4.0; // or (float)total / 4;
printf("Average: %f\n", avg);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int loop, money, total, avg;

    total = 0;
    loop = 0;

    while(loop < 4) {
        printf("Money Spent");
        scanf("%d", &money);
        total = total + money;
        loop = loop + 1;
    }
    avg = total / 4;
    printf("Average %d", avg);

    getch();
}
```

**Note that &avg gives you an index that's the address of avg, in this case, 2686776. Not avg itself.**

Be careful not to confuse the address referring to a memory location with the value stored in the location.